# How to resume html5 video after error or abort event occurs

Tags: html, html5-video

I am using video in my page and wanted to check if video stops streaming due to slow network and network connection lost through Chrome's dev tools throttling & offline option in network panel.

But if abort/error event occurs I was not able to play or resume video. HTML5 Video player becomes unresponsive. I tested this on Chrome V 55.0

what I can do to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to solve the same issue and the following workaround

```
this.onErrorHandler = (error) => {
        // some error handling code

        // we are using React, so I use refs, here you can use usual dom getElementById etc methods            
        const video = this.refs.video; 
        video.setAttribute("src", "your videourl");
    };
```

worked for me.